# How to set setStackFromEnd(true); in GridLayoutManager for Recyclerview?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I want Grid layout that loads data from last for that I used following code

```
GridLayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
//       LinearLayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerViewLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
lv_explore.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
```

it gives me error like this

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GridLayoutManager does not support stack from end. Consider using reverse layout
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(GridLayoutManager.java:107)
at in.co.ans.jalsounique.FragmentExplore.onCreateView(FragmentExplore.java:86)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

when I am using `LinearLayoutManager` it is working but I need grid view, please advise what should be better way?

Answer (score 1):

It's just what it says: `setStackFromEnd` is not supported.  It's only for lists, not grids.

> Consider using reverse layout

So the way you work around this is to call `setReverseLayout(true)` on your `GridLayoutManager`.

This means you will need to *reverse the entire order of your list*.  If you are appending items meant to show up at the bottom, you will have to insert them at the beginning instead.